# Trashing .Trash and Emptying Trash

Tags: macos, mac, finder, trash

I don't want to sound stupid, but what happens if someone were to delete the `.Trash` folder using Finder and emptied it.

I know it's possible unless there is something that just stops it from happening.

1. `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall finder` can be used to show the folder.
2. Then go to `~/` in finder and delete `.Trash`.
3. Open trash from dock then empty it.

What would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer, **nothing happens**.

If you delete it, `.Trash` will be created again once needed. You can delete it without issues, no matter if you delete from Finder or from command line (`rm`) will back again.

Comment: Don't you just love a self-healing OS? ;)