# Safe to remove - .rnd and .CFUserTextEncoding

Tags: terminal, finder, high-sierra, macos

As a cleanup routine, I remove files from `~/Library/Logs` and `~/Library/Caches` directory.

I also remove `~/.Trash` and `~/.DS_Store`

My question - Is it safe to remove `~/.rnd` and `~/.CFUserTextEncoding`?

What are these files/folders for?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- .CFUserTextEncoding [is used to store defaults for language and encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/82123/mac-whats-cfusertextencoding-for)
- .rnd [is used as entropy bytes to aid in randomness algorithms](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379943/what-is-the-rnd-binary-in-my-folder)
- .DS_Store [holds your Finder preferences for viewing that folder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69467/consequences-of-deleting-ds-store)
- .Trash [is the terminal version of your macOS trash can](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170066/trashing-trash-and-emptying-trash?rq=1)

Deleting files you don't understand is generally considered a really terrible idea. For macs, we sometimes get lucky because the OS will kindly regenerate many of these for you after you delete them, but I would not count on always being saved this way. These files take up nearly no space, do not hurt anything, and deleting them has no benefit and causes their almost immediate recreation.